# Replace singletons with what?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, oop, singleton

Singletons are so often said to be a bad design choice, so how should you design an application when you want to avoid them?

Comment: Check this article: [http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/co-single.html](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/co-single.html)

Comment: They have their uses but like anything you should know when to use them. I would say they could be part of a bad implementation choice rather than a bad design choice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use concepts such [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to inject the services you depend on (basically the singletons you use) to you, instead of providing a global reference to them

Comment: In particular, DI frameworks can simplify a lot of the wiring required, providing the convenience of a singleton, but with better insulation and the possibility to extend to multiple instances in the future, if required.

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents.

Just design your application in such way that it's realy doesn't matter if it's singleton passed to your object or not.

Consider if you have MySingleton.Instance inside -> that looks bad and you are tightly coupled with this. 
If you passed MySignleton as a parameter in a method and it's instantiated outside as a MySingleton.Instance or new MySingleton() -> oh well, I still can mock or change it so it doesn't really matter.